# how to add prompts in skype for business?

Tags: botframework

I created a bot using microsoft bot framework and deployed it on ***skype for business***. 
Now the challenge is i need to add yes/no prompts for a couple of questions.
sample image is attached[image]

How can I add these kind of prompts in skype for business?

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the Skype for Business channel is deprecated: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-skypeforbusiness

> **Skype for Business channel of Bot Framework was deprecated on June 30, 2019.**
>
> Skype for Business channel stopped accepting new bots on June 30, 2019.  Existing bots continued operating through October 31, 2019.  The channel is currently being deprecated, and no production loads should be using it.  Microsoft Teams is the preferred communication tool from Microsoft.  Learn how to [connect your bot to Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/channel-connect-teams).

However, what you're looking for is a type of dialog called a confirm prompt, and dialogs are not channel-specific. I don't know what SDK you're using, but this document explains how to use prompts and links to a sample in several languages: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-dialog-manage-conversation-flow